# References for homology, suitable as background for quantum codes

Tags: mathematics, resource-request

Quantum codes are [often](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.09271.pdf) [related](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05089.pdf) to the concepts in homology, such as chain complexes.

Is there an introduction to homology suitable for building a strong understanding of these results?

I am looking for something longer than the background section of QEC papers. A good book. Perhaps a review article or a PhD thesis. Something that includes worked out examples would be excellent.

Video tutorials or online courses are also acceptable as answers to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Part 3 and 4 of Dan Brown's lecture notes](https://sites.google.com/site/danbrowneucl/teaching/lectures-on-topological-codes-and-quantum-computation) gives an introduction to the basics of homology including worked out examples.

Comment: Thank you, these are an excellent set of notes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion of these topics in Fujii's book:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01444.pdf, and in this paper of Hector Bombin: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0277.pdf

You might also find interesting things here:
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-12358-1

Comment: Fujii's book seems quite useful, as does Bombin's paper.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://video.ethz.ch/events/2014/qec/02_monday/9a78cf9f-83e2-485a-8625-80216e376384.html) you can find a nice tutorial video by Dan Browne on the concepts of Homology and how we can use them to understand surface codes. And here is [the slide deck](https://www.qec14.ethz.ch/slides/DanBrowne.pdf).